# Creating multiple child processes with a single pipe

Tags: unix, process, pipe

I need to create three child processes, each of which reads a string from the command line arguments and writes the string to a single pipe. The parent would then read the strings from the pipe and display all three of them on the screen. I tried doing it for two processes to test and it is printing one of the strings twice as opposed to both of them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char *character1 = argv[1];
    char *character2 = argv[2]; 

    char inbuf[100]; //creating an array with a max size of 100

    int p[2]; // Pipe descriptor array
    pid_t pid1; // defining pid1 of type pid_t
    pid_t pid2; // defining pid2 of type pid_t

    if (pipe(p) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Pipe Failed"); // pipe fail
    }

    pid1 = fork(); // fork

    if (pid1 < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed"); // fork fail
    }

    else if (pid1 == 0){ // if child process 1
        close(p[0]); // close the read end
        write(p[1], character1, sizeof(&inbuf[0])); // write character 1 to the pipe
    }

    else { // if parent, create a second child process, child process 2
        pid2 = fork();  

        if (pid2 < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed"); // fork fail
        }

        if (pid2 = 0) { // if child process 2
            close(p[0]); // close the read end
            write(p[1], character2, sizeof(&inbuf[0])); // write character 2 to the pipe
        }

        else { // if parent process
            close(p[1]); // close the write end

            read(p[0], inbuf, sizeof(&inbuf[0])); // Read the pipe that both children write to 
            printf("%s\n", inbuf); // print 

            read(p[0], inbuf, sizeof(&inbuf[0])); // Read the pipe that both children write to 
            printf("%s\n", inbuf); // print 
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't keep looping until there's no more data to read.  It does a single read.  It also doesn't check the value returned by `read()`, but it should.

I've abstracted the `fork()` and `write()` (and error check) code into a function.  This seems to work:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void child(int fd, const char *string)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    int len = strlen(string);
    if (pid < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%.5d: failed to fork (%d: %s)\n",
                (int)getpid(), errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid > 0)
        return;
    else if (write(fd, string, len) != len)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%.5d: failed to write on pipe %d (%d: %s)\n",
                (int)getpid(), fd, errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        exit(0);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char inbuf[100]; //creating an array with a max size of 100
    int p[2]; // Pipe descriptor array

    if (argc != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s str1 str2 str3\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (pipe(p) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Pipe Failed"); // pipe fail
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        child(p[1], argv[i+1]);

    int nbytes;
    close(p[1]); // close the write end
    while ((nbytes = read(p[0], inbuf, sizeof(inbuf))) > 0)
        printf("%.*s\n", nbytes, inbuf); // print 

    return 0;
}
```

I ran the command multiple times, each time using the command line:

```
./p3 'message 1' 'the second message' 'a third message for the third process'
```

On one run, the output was:

```
the second messagemessage 1
a third message for the third process
```

On another, I got:

```
the second messagemessage 1a third message for the third process
```

And on another, I got:

```
message 1
the second messagea third message for the third process
```

(This is on a MacBook Pro with Intel Core i7, running Mac OS X 10.8.3, and using GCC 4.7.1.)

Comment: I forgot to mention. I tried using the read statement twice and printing twice. It prints the first string two times and not both strings.

Comment: Edited it to include that.

Comment: Since you don't pay any attention to the return value from `read()`, no-one can guess what you're getting back.  Even if you ignore write errors, you must pay attention to what `read()` returns; you don't know how much data is valid unless you look at the number of bytes returned.

Comment: Note that your line `read(p[0], inbuf, sizeof(&inbuf[0]));` is dubious because it reads the size of one character pointer (that's what `sizeof(&inbuf[0])` evaluates to), which might be 4 bytes or 8 bytes.  You should be using `sizeof(inbuf)`, and you should be capturing the number of bytes read so that you only print that many bytes.

Comment: Also, normally, I'd be hassling you about closing the unused ends of the pipes in the child process. In this case, it isn't critical since the child processes do a simple write and then exit, which closes both ends of the pipe.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In your child function, why do say "else { exit 0; } Does the write function in the if statement apply to the last one as well. And why does the value returned by write have to be the same as length?

Comment: It makes sure that the child exits after successfully writing.  If it didn't exit, the child would return, and then continue with the loop in the `main()` function, possibly spawning one or two more children and confusing you completely (and it would fall into the read loop too).  To a moderate approximation, your rephrasing of my code is equivalent to what I wrote — there are bugs in the rephrasing, but the gist is correct.